# az aks get-credentials with custom ssh key?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

So we have our own ssh key pair (mykey.pub / mykey).
User A creates a cluster using:

`az aks create --resource-group XXX --name zzz --ssh-key-value c:\mykey.pub`

Now user A can access the cluster using:

`az aks get-credentials`

Now what if user B wants to access the cluster? There is no --ssh-key-file parameter like acs - where do I need to copy the keys for az aks get-credentials to work?

Thx -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the ssh key is only used to create the cluster and then it can be
>   thrown away?

You are right, in Azure ASK, the ssh key just use for create AKS nodes and ssh to them.

In Azure **ACS**, we need use ssh key to access k8s master VM to download credentials to your local PC.

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=<cluster-resource-group> --name=<cluster-name>
```

This command downloads the cluster credentials to `$HOME/.kube/config`, same as use `scp` to securely copy the file from `$HOME/.kube/config` on the master VM to your local machine. Like this:

```
mkdir $HOME/.kube
scp azureuser@<master-dns-name>:.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config
```

**AKS** managed by Azure platform, `get-credentials` command just **GET** credentials from Azure, API like this:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<your-subscription>/resourceGroups/<your-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/<aks-name>/accessProfiles/clusterUser?api-version=2017-08-31
```

Use **Azure AD token** to get that credentials, so in AKS, we can get credentials without SSH key.

By the way, you can use this command to find how it works:
`az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group> --name <cluster-name> --debug`

Also if you want to allow other members to SSH to AKS nodes, you should send your ssh keys to them:)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to have User B access the cluster is to add User B in your Azure Subscription. Once added, User B can access the cluster in similar manner by using

```
 az aks get-credentials -n "Name of the cluster" -g "Name of the Resourcegroup"
```

Comment: So the ssh key is only used to create the cluster and then it can be thrown away?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the ssh key is used when the VMs for worker nodes are created, so it can be used to ssh to them.

Comment: @user2612030 Yes that's right. Generating ssh key during creation puts Public key path or key contents to install on node VMs for SSH access.